# Connect points to lines so moving points moves line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I'm trying to create a simple sewage system in ArcMap. I want it so that when I move a node/point, the line is moved as well so it needs to be attached to the point (dynamic link?). 
A Point may have have more than one line attached, is this possible to do in ArcMap 10.5.1 (I have Advanced Desktop and Spatial/3D Analyst)?

I've come across Topology as a possible solution. Not sure how to get my two shapefiles/feature classes (point/line) so I can create a topology though.

Edit: Which Ruletype works the best for my problem? I have added the Line and Point feature class to a Topology and using "Add Rule to Topology". I think that is the right approach?

Comment: Yes, using a topology is your solution, but topologies are only available in file/enterprise geodatabase, so the first step is converting your shapefile.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for the Ruletype that works the best for my problem? I have added the Line and Point feature class to a Topology and working on Add Rule to Topology. I think that is the right approach?

Comment: Please update the question.

Comment: Added information to question.

Answer (score 4):

You want to be using Map Topology if you want incident features to move with a point and remain connected. See the mini video below:

[image: Map topology]